# AlarmManager fires too early

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this code in my class:

```
public void setAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StepCountUpdaterAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    Long startOfTommorowMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Long startOfTodayMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Long startOfAlarmMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - startOfTodayMillis;

    Long totalWaitMillis = (startOfTodayMillis + startOfAlarmMillis) - System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(totalWaitMillis < 0) return;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                totalWaitMillis,
                pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                totalWaitMillis,
                pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have this alarm fire at 6:30am UTC every day. To do that I use    `Long totalWaitMillis = (startOfTomorrowMillis + startOfAlarmMillis) - System.currentTimeMillis();` but for testing purposes, i changed it to use `startOfTodayMillis` so i can test the alarm.
I managed to get the calendar to show the correct firing times with `startOfTodayMillis - startOfAlarmMillis`. When i subtract `System.currentTimeMillis()`, it seems to provide the correct amount of millisecond delay for the alarm to fire next. In effect, it calculates the time in milliseconds till it hits 6:30 today (I have not fired it in the past in this scenario). Yet despite this, it fires extremely early and does its task far earlier than expected. When I use `startOfTomorrowMillis + startOfAlarmMillis` as well, it fires practically a day early and multiple times. I am a novice when it comes to working with AlarmManager so any help here would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am aware that these alarm timers are not exact. I expected a few seconds offset but not minutes or near enough a day. To add a bit of detail, I just tried setting the alarm an hour from now, it fired at least 5 times within around 20 seconds, after an initial 30 seconds from the alarm being set. My device currently uses the `setAndAllowWhileIdle` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method shown in the question was to have the alarm work in idle but to repeat itself which is not a feature i have seen available in the AlarmManager from reading its documentation.

My initial misconception with the AlarmManager  was that the `setAndAllowWhileIdle` and `set` methods's second parameter `Long triggerAtMillis` wasn't a count down to the next time it should fire the alarm, **it was the actual time it should fire for the next alarm**. The documentation for the `triggerAtMillis` parameter shown [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and below:

> triggerAtMillis: time in milliseconds that the alarm should go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

Courtesy of @Niaj Mahmud 's I have made my own twist to the answer he provided that works such that it does a scheduled task while the phone is in doze mode/ is idle. In this example I schedule the task at 11:58pm of each day, without the need for a notification.

**Activity.java code:**

```java
    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StepCountUpdaterAlarm.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

**BroadcastReciever.java code**

```java
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyActivity myActivity = MyActivity.getInstance();
        //Do your work here.
       
        myActivity.setAlarm(context); //Set your alarm again to reschedule itself.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For recurring alarm why you are doing like that.. alarm manager already has own method for alarm in every 24 hour.

first create a class with broadcast receiver like

```
                class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
                
                    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
                        Log.d("this", "notify")
                
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                
                            val intent = Intent(context, AlarmActivity2::class.java)
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
                            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
                
                            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "111")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.blue_stringart)
                                .setContentTitle("Alarm is running")
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_24,"Stop",pendingIntent)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                
                            val notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
                            val r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification)
                            r.play()
                
                            val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
                            notificationManagerCompat.notify(123, builder.build())
                
                        }
                
                    }
                
                }
```

after that go to your activity  class make 2 method and call in oncreate

```
            private fun setAlarm1() {
            var calender: Calendar
          calender = Calendar.getInstance()
                        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, PUT_YOUR_ALARM HOUR)
                        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, PUT_YOUR_ALARM MINUTE)
                        calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                    alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    val thuReq: Long = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis + 1
                    var reqReqCode = thuReq.toInt()
                    if (calender.timeInMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                        calender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1)
                    }
                    val alarmTimeMilsec = calender.timeInMillis
                    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)
                    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqReqCode, intent, 0)
            
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calender.timeInMillis,
                       24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,// or AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
                        pendingIntent
                    )
    
    
        private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val name = "Alarmclock Channel"
                val description = " Reminder Alarm manager"
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNELID, name, importance)
                notificationChannel.description = description
                val notificationManager =
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            }
        }
```

Note - ***Must to do***(go to your app setting and give notification permission  on) 1.alarmManager.setRepeating here you can use your alarm type as your wish. 2.requestcode must be unique for each alarm. 3. you must take a alarm time and keep in calender.timeInMillis which is you expecting alarm time.

still problem comments below

Comment: I should have mentioned that I wish for the alarm to be scheduled at a specific point in the day being 6:30AM UTC, as well as it being fired every day at that time. I apologise. If I were to fire it at every 24 hours, depending on when the user downloaded the app, the task would complete at a different time for every user. My goal is to have a set time for this alarm to repeat over and over, it doesnt need to be exact but around 6:30am is what I am aiming for.

Comment: no. I have give you the code for  firing alarm your wanted time everyday..

Comment: alarmManager.setRepeating(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calender.timeInMillis,
                       24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,// or AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
                        pendingIntent
                    )

Comment: calender.timeInMillis  it will be your wanted time .

Comment: My bad again, i didnt look carefully enough at the code. I have tested it and it works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are most welcome .. I have worked with alarm system in production level app.   from here you can take more help https://github.com/Niajnm/Android-RandomUser-Alarm-Trigger/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/randomuser/AlarmClock